# Why ng-transclude no binding data

Tags: angularjs

I am just starting to learn AngularJS. I tried to print the list.
But I met some problem.
May I ask why {{elem.name}} no bind the data?
I always print this:

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

this is my element

Thanks!!

```js
    var App;

    App = angular.module("app", []);

    App.directive('grid', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            template: "<ul><li ng-repeat='elem in list' ng-transclude></li></ul>",
            scope: {
                list: "="
            }
        }

    });


    App.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {
        var i, myList, _i, count;
        myList = [];
        for (i = _i = 1; _i <= 20; i = ++_i) {
            myList.push({
                name: "elem " + i,
            });
        }
        return $scope.myList = myList;
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <grid list="myList" width="200px" margin="20px">
        <p>this is my element {{elem.name}}</p>
    </grid>
</div>
```

Comment: this code functions correctly, if you are experiencing unexpected results, it is somewhere else in the code.  are you receiving any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. If I put the "<p>this is my element {{elem.name}}</p>" in the template and remove "ng-transclude", it will be fine. Why?? I am confused. Thanks!!

Comment: but we have an answer posted with a fiddle that is exactly your code, and it works correctly.  Unless you see any difference between your code and the fiddle that was made?